# Uiimagepickercontroller, volume overlay not work

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, volume

i'm developing an app that use uiimagepickercontroller. The app launches first the uiimagepickercontroller with source type setted to "Camera" and then the user can press a tabbar item to launch the imagepickercontroller with source type on "PhotoSavedAlbums". All it works but not the default volume (the volume that we can set by the hardware buttons of the iphone),with SourceType "Camera" the volume is disabled (and there isn't the overlay with the bell) but with SourceType "SavedPhotosAlbum" the volume works and the overlay with the bell appears. I have noticed that the default behavior of the camera app is the same of my application,but at the same time i've seen many others apps that permits to set volume in imagepickercontroller with sourcetype "Camera". I have tried for many hours,i can't found a solution. Any Ideas? I can't find any audio property that do this work!

Answer (score 1):

The only solution to make visible the overlay volume control is use AVFoundation framework instead of the classic uiimagepickercontroller.